# Copy all the data from an existing database when create the test database. Django

Tags: python, database, django, testing

When I run my tests, I'd like it to copy an existing database with all the data when create the test database.

I never thought about this till one of my colleague uses `POSTGIS_TEMPLATE = DATABASES['default']['NAME']` for his tests. 
Because we use `GeoDjango` for our project, so `POSTGIS_TEMPLATE` exists for letting the test runner know which postgis database template to use.
And when he define it as mentioned above, it actually creates the test database with all the data as well. It's kinda handy for us, so we don't need to create the fixture files.
But if we can not do the same with the projects which do not use `GeoDjango`.

So I have two questions here:
Is it good idea to use the data already exists in the project database? (For some tests, I may need to delete all the data first for a certain table, but in many cases, we test against non empty data set.)
If it's not a bad idea, for the project which does not use `GeoDjango`, is there anyway I can set it to copy the data from the existing database?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to use the pre-existing data in the project database?

No -- it's liable to change, leading to weird nondeterministic behavior in your tests.

The safest option is to dump your existing data with `./manage.py dumpdata`, then load it as a fixture in your individual tests. [This documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#fixture-loading) describes how.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, I'm aware of the loading fixtures way. but If I have a copied database, I do not need to do that. Use `dumpdata` and then load it, it's as same as creating a database with the same data copied anyway no?

Comment: You'll end up with the same data, but your data won't change from test to tests. If you use your prod database to generate test data and your database is changing while you're running your tests, for example, or changes from test run to test run, you risk inconsistent results.

Comment: No, when the test runner got started, it will copy the database, so the test database will not change while running the tests. It may change for the next test run, I should not get inconsistent results unless there are bugs in the code, because the whole point of having tests is to prevent inconsistent results when running against different data set.